# Why does execution of program stop - I caught the exception?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing a unit test framework. I noticed Mocha purports to handle exceptions in your test code gracefully, mapping the exception to the correct test in the log output. I'm attempting to do the same thing here. Let's ignore mapping the exception to the correct test for now (I'll def take a suggestion though, I'm stumped on how I'll do that for now)

I add all the test functions into the testmap, iterate over the keys in the testmap, and call each test's function one by one. I stall till the tests report back completed. I wrap around this a try-catch block to catch any exceptions that happen in any of the tests. It works - I can catch exceptions generated in the tests but even though I catch them, the program terminates. I do not want the program to terminate, and I don't think it's supposed to if you catch the exception... what gives?

Here is the try-catch in my library code

```
this.runtests = () => {
    try {
        Object.keys(this.testmap).forEach((test) => {
            performance.mark(test)
            this.testmap[test].testfunc();           
        });

        this.stalltillgood(() => {
            this.finallog();
        });
    }
    catch (e) {
        console.log('UNHANDLED EXCEPTION IN TEST');
        console.log(e.stack);
    }

};
```

Here is the client code which generates the exception - it is ENOENT - no such file or directory - hello.htm doesn't exist (on purpose)

```
expected('<fuck>&<fuck>');
testinfo('A Hello World Test',                    //the name of the test [MUST PASS TO ACTUAL AS WELL]
 'This is the hello world test doc lol');     //the doc
comparator(cmp.equals);                           //you can use the pre built compare functions or your own
test(() => {                                      //pass your test function to test
    const file = fs.readFileSync('./hello.htm');
    actual('A Hello World Test', file.toString());//make a call to actual in your test code
});                                               //to pass it your test result

//write more tests with the same sequence of commands
```

I think my problem is that this.runtests is the last method called, and after continuing on from my catch block, the program literally never has anything to output to me again, everything should be logged by then. The program just terminates after the catch block. I think I will have an extra var in test 'started' and just restart this.runtests, which will now check to see if a test has been started before trying to start it! Hooray! Still don't know how to map the exception to the proper test, maybe e.stack? Actually yeah that should be easy I guess lol.

Comment: I wish there was a way to really just continue execution of program - that's the error in my thinking, "The program just continues if I catch it." No, it jumps to the catch block and continues from there!

Comment: Looks like I will have to use the line number from e.stack, read the client code file, search for their use of actual which always has the test name as the first argument, and get that string. Ballin'. I figured this one out hooray!

Answer (score 0):

I think my problem is that this.runtests is the last method called, and after continuing on from my catch block, the program literally never has anything to output to me again, everything should be logged by then. The program just terminates after the catch block. I think I will have an extra var in test 'started' and just restart this.runtests, which will now check to see if a test has been started before trying to start it! Hooray! Still don't know how to map the exception to the proper test, maybe e.stack? Actually yeah that should be easy I guess lol.

Comment: Why down vote my question? In this case the answer was simply the program terminates almost right after exiting the catch block. I didn't realize that. Maybe it will help someone. It's not a duplicate question.